# ScrollView scroll with multiple enters in edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview

I have an edit text in scroll view with `maxHeight` set to some value . When i click enter multiple times in edit text after the maxHeight reached, the scroll view starts scrolling and if i continue pressing enter it moves the page to the end of scroll view.

I want the focus should remain in edittext only so that it can remain visible on the screen.

i have tried with `adjustPan` also but its not helping

Comment: Why don't you just disable next button in the softkey?

Comment: I can't user can change line using enter

Comment: I mean when the user reaches limit, then do it.

Comment: i have set maxHeight because of Ui perspective but the edit text can hold any number of character therefore this solution will not work.

Comment: In that case the editText will keep on growing downwards, You'll have to put some limit on that. And if it is not happening then there must be a view under that editText which would prevent the editText to be visible once it's reached.

Comment: maxHeight is putting the limit only

Comment: It is not. MaxLength would put limit.

Comment: From documentation please ref 
Makes the TextView at most this many pixels tall. This option is mutually exclusive with the setMaxLines(int) method. Setting this value overrides any other (maximum) number of lines setting.

Comment: The attribute `maxLines` corresponds to the maximum height of the EditText, it controls the outer boundaries and not inner text lines. For the inside text you need `MaxLength`

Comment: i am talking about outer boundaries only my friend thats why i have mentioned from Ui perspective in my initial comments

Comment: Ok, let me break it down for you: setting maxLines/Height would fix height, but with that if you are not fixing the total length of the text then the scrollview will scroll on next click but textView won't as it's height is fixed. So if you want it to move along with it, don't set maxLines/height, instead set minLines. If you don't want it to scroll along then set maxLength.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do like this one:

```
private int scrollX, 
            scrollY;

private ScrollView.OnScrollChangedListener mOnScrollChangedListener = new ScrollView.OnScrollChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged(ScrollView scrollView, int scrollingX, int scrollingY, int oldScrollingX, int oldScrollingY) {

        scrollView.setScrollX(scrollX);
        scrollView.setScrollY(scrollY);

    }

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview);

    scrollX = scrollView.getScrollX();
    scrollY = scrollView.getScrollY();

}
```